# can't get transaction hash from signTransaction with Etherjs

Tags: ethers.js

I'm trying to create a script that makes a swap transaction and then print out the transaction hash of that submitted transaction, but I keep getting back "undefined" even though I'm expecting something like "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". The trx does go through the network just fine. can someone explain what i must do to get the trx hash? thanks in advance!

```
const ethers = require("ethers");    
const url = 'ws://172.33.x.x:8546';
const router_abi = require('./uniswapABI.json');
var uniswap_address = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'.toLowerCase()
const weth_contract_address = '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2'.toLowerCase();
const contract_address = '0xE7a7De362179108E26E464a39B204a9561B352cf'.toLowerCase();

var accounts = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var pks = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const input = {
    GAS_LIMIT: '428000',
    ETH_AMOUNT: '.01', 
    AMOUNT_OUT: '0'
};

async function Buy_fx11() {
    
    const connection = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);
    const pk_fixed = Buffer.from(pks, 'hex');
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(pk_fixed, connection);
    const signer = wallet.connect(connection)
    const count = await connection.getTransactionCount(wallet.address);

    const router = new ethers.Contract(uniswap_address, router_abi, signer);

    const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        input.AMOUNT_OUT,
        [weth_contract_address,contract_address],
        wallet.address,
        Date.now() + 90000,
        {
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther(input.ETH_AMOUNT),
            gasLimit: input.GAS_LIMIT,
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", "gwei"),
            maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", "gwei"),
            }
        );

    const finaltx = await signer.signTransaction(tx);  
    console.log(finaltx.hash);
}
```

[image: undefined trx hash]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already create `router` with signer, so calling `router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` make it sign and send transaction.

try to use `tx.hash` for get transaction_hash and `tx.wait()` for make sure transaction was mined.